# Adding a link library only for objects compiled from a certain language?

Tags: c++, cmake, cuda, linker-errors

I have a project involving both C++ and CUDA code, and specifically - binaries whose objects originate only from C++ code (compiler with a regular C++ compiler) and binaries whose objects originate only from CUDA code (that is, `.cu` files compiled with `nvcc`).

The thing is, the C++-originated targets still make some CUDA API calls, and thus depend on the CUDA libraries.

Now, for linking the CUDA-originated binaries, I don't need to mention the CUDA libraries; it links fine, but for the C++-originated libraries, I do need them.

How can I tell cmake to `link_libraries` only for my C++-originated targets?

Or - am I thinking about this problem the wrong way?

Note: I'm using CMake >= 3.8 with native CUDA support, so I don't use the `cuda_`-prefixed commands.

Comment: You may just want to use target_link_libraries.

Comment: @drescherjm: But I don't want to set this per-target.

Comment: How do you create CUDA targets? Do you use `cuda_add_executable`, or just `add_executable` with "CUDA" language enabled (in recent CMake versions)?

Comment: @Tsyvarev: See note.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably have distinct targets defined, created e.g. by `add_library` or `add_executable` and then use `target_link_libraries(target_name [PRIVATE | INTERFACE | PUBLIC]library)`.
As a general guideline you shouldn't operate on directory level (link_libraries, include_directories, etc.) it is proposed e.g. by Daniel Pfeifer in [this awesome talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bsXLMQ6WgIk&).

Comment: This is a comment, this doesn't answer my question. You're essentially saying I should _never_ using `link_libraries`. If that's your position, justify it please.

Comment: Well, this solves the original problem, e.g. you can link only C++ targets as you asked for. The idea to not operate on directory level (`link_libraries`, `include_directories`, etc.) is not mine, but is e.g. proposed by Daniel Pfeifer in [this awesome talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bsXLMQ6WgIk). I don't have enough CMake expertise / experience to defend this on my own, but from what I've done with CMake so far, this guidelines certainly help to keep things simple.

Comment: @paler123 you need to amend your answer. please don't add a lot content in your comments.

Comment: @einpoklum This is the recommended approach. Directory level properties should be avoided, as they are not easily tracked and affect any potentially future added targets. I also recommend that talk, it's really good and to the point.

Comment: @compor: With due respect - that is irrelevant. I was asking about _language_ level properties, not directory-level properties.

Comment: @einpoklum AFAIK, there's no such thing as language level [properties](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-properties.7.html) (the categorization used is per scope - global, dir, target, etc). There are `LANG` *related* properties sprinkled over these that are set by various combinations (e.g. user provided flags, enabled languages via `project`, auto-detection using the file prefix, etc.).